# Android, callback when map clustering is completed

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

I am using Google Maps and its clustering utility in my app. Clustering itself is working fine, but I have issue, when I try to deal with configuration changes.

This is my case:

1. User sees a map on a screen, which is a `fragment`.
2. When clustering is completed, markers on map appear. User can interact with `markers`.
3. When user selects a `marker`, it is highlighted and `BottomSheet` is expanded to display.

If user rotates screen (i.e. configuration change happens), I save what marker was selected using `onSaveInstanceState` (actually I do not save marker itself, but only a link to related `List` entry like ID). Then, I want to restore that user selection that was before configuration change.

Clustering itself is executed like this:

```
clusterManager.clearItems();
clusterManager.addItems(eventManager.getEventList());
clusterManager.cluster();
```

This code is executed, when data is received from server. When clustering is executed, all `markers`, obviously, are recreated as well. So in order to highlight previous user selection (previous `marker`), I must know WHEN clustering utility finishes its operation. By that time I am sure that I can safely use such functions like:

```
clusterManager.getRenderer()).getMarker(<param>)
```

and

```
clusterManager.getRenderer()).getClusterItem(<param>)
```

otherwise, these will return `null` sometimes, if clustering task is not completed yet.

However, I cannot find a reasonable way, how to get a response from clustering utility (i.e. `ClusterManager`), when clustering is completed. I think I need to update this standard clustering code:

```
 /**
     * Runs the clustering algorithm in a background thread, then re-paints when results come back.
     */
    private class ClusterTask extends AsyncTask<Float, Void, Set<? extends Cluster<T>>> {
        @Override
        protected Set<? extends Cluster<T>> doInBackground(Float... zoom) {
            mAlgorithmLock.readLock().lock();
            try {
                return mAlgorithm.getClusters(zoom[0]);
            } finally {
                mAlgorithmLock.readLock().unlock();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Set<? extends Cluster<T>> clusters) {
            mRenderer.onClustersChanged(clusters);
        }
    }
```

I think, that `onPostExecute` should provide a response not to `Renderer` only, but to a user of `ClusterManager` (like my `fragment`) that clustering is done. But I do not want to modify standard code.

Is there a better way how to handle this case?

Comment: Have you tried using `OnMapLoadedCallback`? According to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback) `onMapLoaded()` is called when the map has finished rendering

Comment: Well, it might be fine, but the problem is that I can draw markers and clusters just after data is received from server, but sometimes map is loaded before data is received (due to connectivity issues etc.). So probably this will not work.

Comment: did you find any way to listen the cluster done event or some sort?

Answer (score 2):

You are going about this the wrong way.

You should implement:

```
class YourClusterItemRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<YourClusterItem>
```

and set it to ClusterManager as renderer like this:

```
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new YourClusterItemRenderer(...));
```

Override YourClusterItemRenderer's methods `onBeforeClusterItemRendered` and `onBeforeClusterRendered` and there you can change what each marker looks like according to your logic as per parameters from your server.

So when ClusterManager finishes rendering all your markers already look like you want them according to user state etc.